How to retrieve sensitivity labels associated with user using API or .NET?
I’m trying to pull a list of sensitivity labels associated with a specific user using the Microsoft Graph API, but I’m hitting a wall. Here’s the API call I tried:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

Unfortunately, I got a 400 Bad Request error and the message said something about an unexpected segment:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unexpected segment DynamicPathSegment. Expected property/$value.",
        ...
    }
}

I also tried this in C# like this:
var result = await graphClient.Users["{id}"].Security.InformationProtection.SensitivityLabels.GetAsync();

But I ran into this error:
CS1061 'UserItemRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Security'...

Has anyone successfully retrieved sensitivity labels for a user? If so, could you point me in the right direction? I’d really appreciate any help!

You need to use /beta endpoint to retrieve sensitivity labels using Graph API.

Hi @CarolBradley Any update?

Note that, retrieving sensitivity labels associated with user via MS Graph API is available only in Beta version not in v1.0.
I have below list of sensitivity labels associated with user of my tenant:

Now, I registered one app and granted InformationProtectionPolicy.Read.All permission of Application type with admin consent like this:

When I ran below API with v1.0 endpoint using token generated with client credentials flow, I too got same error:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to use /beta endpoint where I got the response with labels details successfully as below:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

Response:

Reference:
List sensitivityLabels - Microsoft Graph beta
